# Comparing two column values in postgres

Tags: sql, sql-update, case, postgresql-9.1

I have table having following columns and records. I need to compare the two column values(ColumnA and ColumnB), if ColumnB>ColumnA then and update the third column from 'N' TO 'Y'

```
CREATE TABLE Test(ColumnA int,ColumnB int,Result Varchar(2))

INSERT INTO Test values(1,3,'N')
INSERT INTO Test values(2,1,'N')
INSERT INTO Test values(1,5,'N')
INSERT INTO Test values(8,7,'N')
```

I need to update Result Column='Y' for first and third row because columnB>ColumnA

Result

```
ColumnA   ColumnB Result
1          3      Y
2          1      N
1          5      Y
8          7      N
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: currently our client machine is using this version so not able to upgrade now.is it possible achieve this in 9.1?

Comment: You might want to send your client this link: https://why-upgrade.depesz.com/show?from=9.1&to=12&keywords=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update test
set result = 
    case
        when columnb > columna then 'Y'
        else 'N'
    end;
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: is anything new in your answer that does not cover the 1st answer?

Comment: By the time I could have checked, enter was pressed. So time is different.@ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Comment: @Ram this answer is given later than the 1st one but accepted it starange?

Comment: Sorry pal, I don't want to argue @ZaynulAbadinTuhin

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with a simple CASE expression:

```
update test
  set result = case 
                 when columna > columnb then 'Y' 
                 else 'N' 
               end
;
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/ZHIUZD82060

---

I would recommend to use a `boolean` column instead of a `varchar` to store "yes/no" flags. Then the update becomes as simple as `set result = column_a > columnb`

Comment: as per your suggestion.i changed the data type to boolean. Thank you.